# Convert rows of a pandas dataframe into one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Joe', 1: 'Carl', 2: 'Anton'},
                   'Level': {0: 'Beginner', 1: 'Pro', 2: 'Intermediate'},
                   'Experience': {0: 0, 1: 15, 2: 7},
                   'record_number': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}})
```

```
  Name   Level          Experience  record_number
0    Joe      Beginner   0          1            
1   Carl           Pro  15          2            
2  Anton  Intermediate   7          3
```

The output should look like this:

```
     Name_1   Level_1  Experience_1  Name_2  Level_2  Experience_2  Name_3      Level_3  Experience_3
0       Joe  Beginner             0    Carl      Pro            15   Anton Intermediate             7
```

So the row should be placed into the same row, one after another, whereby the column names should get their index from the record_number column.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`set_index('record_number')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), then flatten the columns:

```
out = df.set_index('record_number').stack().to_frame().T

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
```

Output:

```
  Name_1   Level_1 Experience_1 Name_2 Level_2 Experience_2 Name_3       Level_3 Experience_3
0    Joe  Beginner            0   Carl     Pro           15  Anton  Intermediate            7
```

Comment: 'record_number' columns should not be in the result